# How do i exclude a code in php if a parameter is meat?

Tags: php

I'm making a cms, I have the index.php in this code .

```
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){

echo "posts from cat";

}

if(isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['post'])){

echo "post and category title ";
//this is the post page
}
```

How do i exclude first cat from echo the code if i go to the post page  ?

Comment: Err...using if else?

Comment: Move the 2nd one above the 1st and then use elseif

Comment: i do that now it works

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && !isset($_GET['post'])){

  echo "posts from cat";

} elseif(isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['post'])){

 echo "post and category title ";
 //this is the post page
}
```

Comment: it works, I forgot about elseif just staring to make websites

Comment: @JohnBook Glad to help.